# Does the Banach-Alaoglu theorem imply finite dimensionalness?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a normed separable vector space $X$, the Banach-Alaoglu theorem states that the closed unit ball in the dual space $X^*$ is compact in the weak-* topology. Since $X$ is separable, that topology is metrizable.

Now, the Alaoglu theorem states that for any normed vector space, the closed unit ball is compact iff the space is finite dimensional. Applying this to $X^*$ allegedly yields that $X^*$ is finite dimensional (obviously false).

Where is my mistake?

Comment: If $X$ is not finite-dimensional then the weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ is strictly weaker than  the norm-induced topology of $X^*. $

Comment: the closed unit ball is compact iff the space is finite dimensional: Riesz theorem not Banach-Alaoglu

Comment: Finite dimensional is the trivial cases. You do not see anything. That is the space is trivially separable and the weak-* topology coincide with the norm topology and then the space is separable, the unite ball is compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Compact" in the second theorem refers to the norm topology, not the weak-* topology.  The weak-* topology may be metrizable, but that metric does not come from a norm.

Comment: You mean *a* norm topology? Or am I missing why should there be a unique norm on that space (up to equivalence)? Also, isn't the metric induced by the norm $\|x\|=d(x,0)$?

Comment: My point is, it still seems to me that the weak-* topology is induced by a norm, and therefore the Alaoglu theorem applies to the compactness w.r.t that norm

Comment: No, the weak-* topology is not induced by a norm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand this is the fine point I got wrong. But why doesn't the norm $\|x\|=d(x,0)$ induce the same topology as $d(\cdot,\cdot)$? It seems convergences in these two cases would be equivalent

Comment: If $d$ is a metric corresponding to the weak-* topology, $d(x,0)$ is not a norm.  One reason it can't be a norm: every weak-* neighbourhood of $0$ contains infinite rays from the origin.

Comment: Take $\{x_n\}$ to be the dense countable set in the unit ball of $X$, and define $\forall \psi\in X^*$: $\|\psi\|:=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{2^n}|\psi(x_n)| $. This is a norm. It induces the weak* topology, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it does not induce the weak * topology. $\{\psi: \|\psi\| < 1\}$ is not a weak-* neighbourhood of $0$.